# Can't move debugger yellow cursor after exception thrown

Tags: visual-studio-2019, resharper

When an exception occurs in debug mode. I would quite often go back to the previous line with the yellow debugger arrow, edit the code, then keep running step by step.

It seems that now when some kind of exceptions are thrown, it's not possible to move the debugger cursor until the exception has been caught. Is there a workaround to make this work again?

That makes the progress of quick testing much more difficult.

EDIT:

- This appeared after updating to vs 16.8 (then 16.8.1)
- Issue occurs with .NET 5 or .NET 3.1, or .NET framework 4.7.2, not a framework issue
- I uninstalled Resharper to rule this out
- if I just do throw new exception("Pause"); or do a divide by zero it will not cause the issue.
- if it is involving Sytstem.Linq then I will have the issue.

Example:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

namespace TestDebug
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
         
            int[] test = null;

            var error = test.Any();

            Console.WriteLine("Bye bye World!");
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT2:
The tooltip is different in my example from what I would see with a different exception such as a divide by zero exception. (see comment).

The tooltip when I can't drag the cursor is saying:
"This is the next statement to execute when this thread returns from the current function"

It does not suggest to drag the cursor as it would normally do

Comment: What have you tried so far? If you suspect ReSharper then have you disabled or uninstalled it? Did it used to work, what has changed since then? Have you tried a fresh test application? What language are you using? You need to give move details. If it helps at all it still works for me for C# (.net 5) with Visual Studio 2019 16.8.1 and ReSharper 2020.3 EAP7)

Comment: thanks, same config .Net 5, vs 2019 16.8.1 and resharper EAP7, only change leading to the issue was updating vs. I'll edit the question accordingly to reduce possibilities. Could you confirm if you don't have the issue with my example please?

Comment: Thanks for updating the details in your question. I have tried your example and can drag the 'debug cursor' indicator to previous statements and re-run. BTW, the 'debug cursor' indicator is not yellow at the point of the exception but does turn yellow when it is moved.

Comment: With an operation such as 1/0 I see exception with yellow arrow and it says: "This is the next statement that will be executed. To change which statement is executed next, drag the arrow..."  whereas on my example the arrow is green and the tooltip says: "This is the next statement to exectute when this thread returns from the current function."

Comment: I get the same and can drag the arrow in both cases - are you able to too? I assume you have the `Options`->`Debugging`->`General`->`Enable Edit and Continue` enabled?

Comment: yes a disabling it doesn't change anything. I can still edit and continue with DivideByZeroException (which leaves the cursor yellow when triggered)

Comment: but thank you, you just lead me to the correct route. I've done a reset of all settings and that fixed the issue. Will do a new export and compare settings to see if I can identify the culprit.

Comment: too many settings changed after reset, I am not able to tell which one is culprit

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and resolved it by ticking this checkbox :

Tools -> Options... -> Editor -> (Window Settings) tick the checkbox "Drag-and-Drop Text Editing"
[tick the checkbox "Drag-and-Drop Text Editing" to be able to click-&-drag the yellow debbuger cursor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/htwwr.jpg)